# How do I print a value from an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having problems with the following code:

```
# THIS FUNCTION CONNECTS TO MY DATABASE
function createSQLconnection(&$connection) {
    $connection = mysqli_connect("typical", "yaddayadda", "crap");
    // mysql_select_db("db", $connection);
    if (!$connection) {
        return "500";
    } else {
        return "200";
    }
}

# THIS FUNCTION GETS ALL LOGS FROM MY DATABASE
function getLogs($conn, &$list, &$length) {
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `db`.`logs`';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $i = 0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $list[$i] = $row;
            $i++;
        }
        $length = $i;
    }
}

createSQLconnection($conn);
getLogs($conn, $logList, $logLength);
```

Everything seems fine up until this point:

```
for($row=0; $row<$logLength; $row++) {
    echo $logList['photo_id'][$row];
    echo $logList['name'][$row];
    echo $logList['location'][$row];
}
```

No errors at all, no problems, just no text.

And even more confusing yet, when I dump the array:

```
print_r($logList);
```

Everything comes out just fine:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [uid] => 1
        [name] => John Doe
        [location] => Main Office
        [photo_id] => State
        [timestamp] => 1473365714
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [uid] => 2
        [name] => Joe Blow
        [location] => New Office
        [photo_id] => Passport
        [timestamp] => 1473365738
    )
)
```

I really don't understand. It should be so simple. Am I doing something wrong? What could I have possibly missed?

Comment: The keys for the different dimensions of the array are in the wrong order.

Comment: Just change the orders. Example: from `['photo_id'][$row]` to `[$row]['photo_id']`

Comment: Just use `foreach` and simplify your life.